# How to access a property of an object of an array from a function scoped inside of that object

Tags: javascript, javascript-objects

```
function CreateInfoBoxCard(){
      var newBox = { 
                "location":currentLoc, // dynamically set location at the time of Creation
                "addHandler":"mouseover", 
                "infoboxOption": { 
                title: 'title', 
                description: "description",
                actions: [{
                    label:'Remove This',
                    eventHandler: function () {
                        removeBox(currentLoc) 
                // WANT TO USE THIS "CurrentLoc AT THAT TIME" AS ID TO REMOVE THIS OBJECT LATER
                //but it will always take "current location" as param, which I don't want
                    }
                }] }
             
            }
           setState((Collection)=>[...Collection, new])
}
```

This is an object which will pushed inside of an array and which will be one infobox in bing map. eventHandler key creates a button on each Info card on bing map. Now onclick of that button I want to remove This particular object based on "location" key (1st key of the object). Here, currentLoc variable is dynamic. So If I click remove button it will remove the infobox of current location, not the location at time of info box created. So, I want to access the value of "location" key of this object and pass it  in removeBox("//pass here//") fuction instead of passing currentLoc variable here. So, how can I access "location" key from this function?

Comment: You cannot use `new` as a variable name, it's a reserved word in Javascript.

Comment: @connexo yes sorry, but its just an example, I wrote here directly. I didn't write new in my code

Answer (score 0):

The object containing the `location` should be accessible to the eventHandler defined in the actions. So, to use it, simply use `obj.location`. This would allow for the eventHandler to always get the latest value even if it is changed after creation.

Going with the above approach, the above code would change to:

```js
function CreateInfoBoxCard(){
    var card = { 
        location: "currentLoc", 
        addHandler: "mouseover", 
        infoboxOption: { 
            title: "title", 
            description: "description",
            actions: [{
                label: "Remove This",
                eventHandler: function () {
                    removeBox(card.location); 
                }
            }]
        }
    }

    return card;
}

function removeBox(location) {
    //Some logic to remove a box
    console.log(location);
}

//Calling `CreateInfoBoxCard` function to get a new card
var card1 = CreateInfoBoxCard();
card1.infoboxOption.actions[0].eventHandler();

//Updating the location of the card and calling it's eventHandler again
card1.location = "someNewLocation";
card1.infoboxOption.actions[0].eventHandler();
```

**Note:** The object name must be changed (to card, for example) since `new` is a restricted keyword.

Comment: But this object will not have any name when it will be pushed inside of an array which is a collection of similar objects. so after creation, I will do this- setState((cardCollection)=>[...cardCollection, new]), append to the array and save it in state variable. So I can't write new.location or card.location